# Cast to datetime - DateTime column with date and nvarchar column with time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a column Date which is Datetime type. And I have an nvarchar column with the time inside. For example:

```
    Date(datetime)                            Time(nvarchar)
-----------                                  ----------
2010-06-08 00:00:00.000                         17:30
```

How can I concatenate them to 2010-06-08 17:30:00.000 as a datetime object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one (*it's works on version 2005 and higher*) -

```
DECLARE 
      @Date DATETIME 
    , @Time NVARCHAR(5)

SELECT 
      @Date = '2010-06-08 00:00:00.000'
    , @Time = '17:30'   

SELECT @Date + @Time
```

Output:

```
2010-06-08 17:30:00.000
```

Comment: Interesting. I have no idea how and why this works, but apparently it does :)

Comment: I am always glad to help. I think this also will be interesting for you: `SELECT LEFT(CAST('2010-06-08 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME), 11)`

Comment: @NenadZivkovic `17:30` is implicitly converted to `1900-01-01 17:30:00.000`. `datetime` + `datetime` produces a result datetime based on the relative difference of both compared to `1900-01-01`. So for example `SELECT GETDATE() + GETDATE()` returns `2126-10-14 03:41:09.327`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I don't have SQL server 2005 installed on my machine here. I only have oracle. But I found this in one of my TSQL snippets folder.

```
SELECT theDate + CAST(theTime AS TIME);
```

Comment: TIME Datatype is introduced in SQL Server 2008

Comment: Well, my bad. Haven't really worked on SQL Server 2005, so all my snippets are from 2008. Did not know that. Thanks!